# How can I obtain AMQP message headers values using lapin?

Tags: rust, rabbitmq

How can I obtain the values in the message headers of an AMQP message via crate lapin (RabbitMQ client)?

I am trying to obtain the values of message headers from the lapin::message::Delivery struct.
I am using Delivery.properties.headers() which returns Option<amq_protocol_types::FieldTable>

How do I read the values in the FieldTable?

Are there any examples that show how to do so?

```
    let mut consumer = channel
        .basic_consume(
            "hello",
            "my_consumer",
            BasicConsumeOptions::default(),
            FieldTable::default(),
        )
        .await?;

    while let Some(delivery) = consumer.next().await {
        let (_, delivery2) = delivery.expect("error in consumer");
        message_cnt+=1;
        let payload_str:String = match String::from_utf8(delivery2.data.to_owned()) {//delivery.data is of type Vec<u8>
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
        };          
        let log_message:String=format!("message_cnt is:{}, delivery_tag is:{}, exchange is:{}, routing_key is:{}, redelivered is:{}, properties is:'{:?}', received data is:'{:?}'"
            ,&message_cnt
            ,&delivery2.delivery_tag
            ,&delivery2.exchange
            ,&delivery2.routing_key
            ,&delivery2.redelivered
            ,&delivery2.properties//lapin::BasicProperties Contains the properties and the headers of the message.
            ,&payload_str
        );
        let amqp_msg_headers_option:&Option<amq_protocol_types::FieldTable>=delivery2.properties.headers();
        let amqp_msg_headers:&amq_protocol_types::FieldTable=match amqp_msg_headers_option{
            None=>{
                let bt=backtrace::Backtrace::new();
                let log_message=format!(">>>>>At receive_message_from_amqp(), message received has no headers, backtrace is '{:?}'",&bt);
                slog::error!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
                let custom_error=std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, &log_message.to_string()[..]);
                return std::result::Result::Err(Box::new(custom_error));
            }
            ,Some(amqp_msg_headers)=>{amqp_msg_headers}
        };
        if amqp_msg_headers.contains_key("worker_id"){
            //let worker_id2:String=amqp_msg_headers.get("worker_id").into();
            let amqp_msg_headers_btm:&std::collections::BTreeMap<amq_protocol_types::ShortString, lapin::types::AMQPValue>=amqp_msg_headers.inner();
            let worker_id2_option=amqp_msg_headers_btm.get(lapin::types::AMQPValue::ShortString("worker_id".into()));
        }
        delivery2
            .ack(BasicAckOptions::default())
            .await?;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution of sorts. This entails the use of serde_json. I made use of serde_json to obtain serde_json::Value object from the object of amq_protocol_types::FieldTable obtained from the properties field of lapin::message::Delivery.
I then processed the serde_json::Value to obtain the header key and value.
Below is the function I have written for the above logic.

```
fn extract_amqp_msg_headers_values(
    my_slog_logger:&slog::Logger
    ,amqp_msg_headers_basic_properties:&lapin::BasicProperties
)->std::result::Result<std::collections::HashMap<String,String>, Box<std::io::Error>> {
    let mut amqp_msg_headers_hm:std::collections::HashMap<String,String>=std::collections::HashMap::new();
    let amqp_msg_headers_option=amqp_msg_headers_basic_properties.headers();
    let amqp_msg_headers=match amqp_msg_headers_option{
        None=>{
            let bt=backtrace::Backtrace::new();
            let log_message=format!(">>>>>At extract_amqp_msg_headers_values(), message received has no headers, backtrace is '{:?}'",&bt);
            slog::error!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
            let custom_error=std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, &log_message.to_string()[..]);
            return std::result::Result::Err(Box::new(custom_error));
        }
        ,Some(amqp_msg_headers)=>{amqp_msg_headers}
    };
    //let mut worker_id2:String="".to_owned();
    let amqp_msg_headers_btm:&std::collections::BTreeMap<amq_protocol_types::ShortString, lapin::types::AMQPValue>=amqp_msg_headers.inner();
    let amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_option=serde_json::to_value(&amqp_msg_headers_btm);
    let amqp_msg_headers_serde_value:serde_json::value::Value=match amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_option{
        Err(err)=>{
            let bt=backtrace::Backtrace::new();
            let log_message=format!(">>>>>At extract_amqp_msg_headers_values(), pos 2b, some error has been encountered transforming amqp_msg_headers to json, amqp_msg_headers is:'{:?}', error is:'{:?}', backtrace is '{:?}'",&amqp_msg_headers,&err,&bt);
            slog::error!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
            let custom_error=std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, &log_message.to_string()[..]);
            return std::result::Result::Err(Box::new(custom_error));
        }
        ,Ok(serde_json_value)=>{serde_json_value}
    };
    
    let serde_json_map:&serde_json::Map<String,serde_json::Value>=amqp_msg_headers_serde_value.as_object().unwrap();
    
    let amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key_vec2:Vec<String>=serde_json_map.keys().cloned().collect();
    for amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key2 in amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key_vec2{
        let amqp_msg_headers_serde_value2:&serde_json::value::Value=&serde_json_map[&amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key2];
        let serde_json_map3:&serde_json::Map<String,serde_json::Value>=amqp_msg_headers_serde_value2.as_object().unwrap();
        
        let some_header_key:String=remove_quotes(&amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key2).to_owned();
        
        let amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key_vec3:Vec<String>=serde_json_map3.keys().cloned().collect();
        for amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key3 in amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key_vec3{
            let some_header_value:String=remove_quotes(&serde_json_map3[&amqp_msg_headers_serde_value_key3].to_string()).to_owned();
            
            amqp_msg_headers_hm.insert(some_header_key.to_owned(),some_header_value.to_owned());
        }
    }
    //slog::info!(my_slog_logger," amqp_msg_headers_hm is:'{:?}'",&amqp_msg_headers_hm);
    Ok(amqp_msg_headers_hm)
}
/// This is a general purpose function to strip double quotes surrounding the supplied &str value.
pub fn remove_quotes(some_str:&str)->&str
{
    // The trimmed string is a slice to the original string, hence no new
    // allocation is performed
    let chars_to_trim: &[char] = &['"',' ', ','];
    let some_str: &str = some_str.trim_matches(chars_to_trim);
    //println!("some_str is:'{}'", some_str);
    return some_str;
}
```